# DictReader is skipping two lines of my file?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv file with the format:

`date, open, high, low,..`

```
22-11-14, 660.6, 15.1, 12.6

22-11-13, 569.6, 13.1, 10.2

22-11-12, 716.0, 18.6, 13.2

....
```

when opening the file with csv.DictReader, and then reading the data row by row, it skips the headers date, open etc; but it is also skipping the first row of data?? the data on date 22-11-14 is being skipped and it starts with 22-11-13??
Here is my code, anyone know why this is and how I can solve it??

```
types = [("Date", str), ("Open", float), ("High", float),
     ("Low", float), ("Close", float), ("Volume", int), ("Adj Close", float)]

input_file = csv.DictReader(open("googlePrices.csv"))
dataList = []    
for rows in input_file:
    rows.update((key, conversion(rows[key])) for key, conversion in types))
    rows['Date'] = time.strptime(rows['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    dataList.append(rows)
```

so in the datalist list, the first element is the data for 22-11-13 and then from there on it works perfectly.. but i need the 22-11-14 to be put into the list??

Comment: Does the file have mixed line endings? I have seen files created on OS X where the header row ends with an `\r`so the header and first row are treated as a single row.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.. how would I find that out??

Comment: You would probably need to open the file in a text editor that has the ability to show line endings. That would be dependent on your OS.

Comment: if you have notepad++ you can show newline chars/show all chars in the textfile. if you dont have notepad++... get notepad++ :P

Comment: I opened it in notepad++ and at the end of each line it has "LF" in bold

Answer (score 0):

If your file is really formatted as you describe, you may need to put commas between the column names

```
date, open, high, low
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it actually already has commas between them all the entire csv file is comma seperated even the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link to a googlePrices.csv file on the internet. I took your basic script and cleaned it up a bit below:

```
import csv
import time

types = [("Date", lambda d: time.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')), ("Open", float), ("High", float),
         ("Low", float), ("Close", float), ("Volume", int),
         ("Adj Close", float)]

with open("googlePrices.csv") as f:
    input_file = csv.DictReader(f)
    dataList = []    
    for rows in input_file:
        rows.update((key, conversion(rows[key])) for key, conversion in types)
        dataList.append(rows)

    print dataList[0]  # shows the first row
```

Here are the first two rows of the file:

```
$ head -n 2 googlePrices.csv
"Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adj Close"
"2012-11-14",660.66,662.18,650.5,652.55,1668400,652.55
```

This is my output:

```
$ python reader.py
{'Volume': 1668400, 'Adj Close': 652.55, 'High': 662.18, 'Low': 650.5, 'Date': time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=319, tm_isdst=-1), 'Close': 652.55, 'Open': 660.66}
```

Your code as shown does not have any issues with it. Either there is something wrong with the file with non printable characters, or your code isn't as you pasted it. I am also pretty sure this is some kind of homework problem [based on my Google-fu](https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/topic.php?id=10246).

Comment: Thanks very much! I did that and it prints 2012-11-13 as the first row :/
I'm gonna download the file again, might have gotten corrupted.. cause my code is exactly the same except I have a lot of functions, but this was the piece that needed fixing haha yeah it is a bit of homework im only new to python haha but that wasnt me that posted that on the other site lol